# Why can't FindControl find a password field on my form?

Tags: asp.net, findcontrol

If this is not possible, how can I get the password out of the field?

```
    dim pw1 as textbox, password as string
    pw1 = ctype(FindControl("PasswordStr"), textbox)
    password = pw1.text
```

Nope: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This code is in a sub that I am calling on a button click

---

Edited by: rockinthesixstring

Here's what the OP said his ASPX markup looks like

```
<form runat="server" id="form1">
  <p>
    <label for="passwordStr">Password</label>
    <input type="text" textmode="password" id="passwordStr" name="passwordStr" maxlength="50">  
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the view code for the textbox control.

Comment: Can you post the aspx part of the page?

Comment: I tried both: <p><label for="passwordStr">Password</label><input type="text" textmode="password" id="passwordStr" name="passwordStr" maxlength="50"></p> and <p><label for="passwordStr">Password</label><input type="password" id="passwordStr" name="passwordStr" maxlength="50"></p>

Comment: Based on that comment I don't think your using a server control see my answer

Comment: You need `runat="server"` as well as `id="..."` in order to use FindControl.  If this is ASP.NET (as per your tags) then use `<asp:TextBox>` with a TextMode of 'password' instead.

Comment: yes, you guys are right. i am missing runat=server and these inputs where just <input type= instead of <asp:TextBox

Comment: @rg89 - for future, it would be good if you put your updated code in your question (edit) instead of in a comment. Comments can't format code as nicely as questions.

Comment: sorry, this interface is not the easiest to navigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using server control's by the looks of things (based on your comment)

Use a control on the aspx page like below:

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" ID="passwordInput" runat"server"></asp:TextBox>
```

You can access a server control from the code behind file using

```
passwordInput.Text
```

Answer (score 2):

If the password field isn't in another "container" like a repeater, then you can simply just access it.

What is the ID of your password field?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="password" runat="server" />
```

You access it like this:

```
pw1 = txtPassword.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your password field is simply an ASP.NET Control on your page (not nested in another control such as a GridView ItemTemplate), you can just do this:

```
string password = PasswordStr.Text;
```

Comment: This will work if `PasswordStr` is not nested in another control.

Comment: You can find it on PageLoad as well, providing it exists. The OP is saying that the compiler isn't finding the control.

Comment: @rg89: You need runat="server" on your controls to be able to use FindControl, and to access your controls in this way in the code-behind.  See my comment on your original question, or Jack Marchetti's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know what your ASPX looks like, we're kinda shooting in the dark.

ASSUMING you have an aspx that looks like this

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" DefaultFocus="formVw$txtName">
    <div>
        <asp:FormView ID="formVw" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                Name: 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
    </div>
</form>
```

You would find the control like this

```
TextBox tb = this.FindControl("form1$formVw$txtName") as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
{
    //Access TextBox control
}
```

The code you originally posted is looking for the control within the `Form` which means, if you have another control (`FormVw` for example), then your code wont find the nested textbox.

---

### EDIT

You said your form looks like this

```
<form runat="server" id="form1">
  <p>
    <label for="passwordStr">Password</label>
    <input type="text" textmode="password" id="passwordStr" name="passwordStr" maxlength="50">  
  </p>
</form>
```

Change it to this

```
<form runat="server" id="form1">
  <p>
    <label for="passwordStr">Password</label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="password" ID="passwordStr" maxlength="50">  
  </p>
</form>
```

Then access the password field like this

```
string password = passwordStr.Text;
```

Comment: my page looks like this essentially: <form runat="server" id="form1"><p><label for="passwordStr">Password</label><input type="text" textmode="password" id="passwordStr" name="passwordStr" maxlength="50"></p></form> i don't use visual studio.

Comment: if your form is that simple, you can simply do what others have said. `string password = PasswordStr.Text;`. `FindControl` is only useful if you have nested controls.